# Multidimensional arrays in eigen library

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, eigen

3 simple questions about the usage and future of the excellent eigen library:

1. Does it have a reason why the access to Matrices is not possible via `matrix[i][j]`, but only via `matrix(i,j)`?
2. Are there plans to implement such a syntax?
3. Will there be an implementation of multidimensional arrays `matrix[n][m]...[l]`?

I really like the eigen library, it is fast and easy to use. The only thing missing for me are really multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Why can't you make a multidimensional array of a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for the `eigen` library because I've never used it, but I can speak to the design of the code. In order to use the `[][]` notation, that typically means that the matrix is built upon underlying vectors that have also overloaded the `[]` operator.

It's possible the author of the `eigen` library did not want to go through the trouble of defining vectors to be the basis of the matrix classes.

Take the following example.

```
class Matrix {
   Vector& operator[](std::size_t ind);
};

class Vector {
   double& operator[](std::size_t ind);
};
```

Allows us to use the `Matrix` class like this:

```
Matrix matrix;
matrix[0][0] = 1.2;
```

Where as defining the peren operator is typically easier because it doesn't also rely on the implementation of a `Vector` class:

```
class Matrix {
    double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j);
    const double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const;
};
```

Allows us to use the `Matrix` class like this:

```
Matrix matrix;
matrix(4, 3) = 9.2;
```

Comment: Can confirm this, we had a semester long project in undergrad to create a matrix library, we were required to overload [] for *matrix* operations, it was a pain, way simpler to just use paren operator syntax. If you want to account for sparse matrices, you'll need intermediary objects in order to deal with predictable sparseness (ie triangular or diagonal matrices).  Doing any kind of complex matrix optimization with bracket operators is annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Multidimensional arrays are supported through the new Tensor module:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html

Comment: I recently found that out too. But I can't get it to work. If you are familiar with this module, could you take a look at [my other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029466/problems-using-eigens-tensor-class)?

Comment: In fact, tensors aren't simply multidimensional arrays, they have a great bunch of mathematical properties related to coordinate system they're viewed from.