# Problems using eigens Tensor class

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to use [eigens Tensor class from the unsupported module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html). This site suggests to include something like `#include <Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>` to be able to use it. I installed eigen via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (Version 3.2.4) on my Mac on OS X Yosemite. Although I get eigen to work properly, I cannot find the necessary module in the unsupported folder:

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/???>
```

What might I have forgotten or done wrong? Or do I have an outdated version which does not have yet the Tensor class?

Comment: at least on both windows and linux (debian) the correct include path is ```#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unsupported Tensor module is only found in the unstable version for now (Current stable: 3.2.5).

Comment: I don't see it in 3.2.8 (the latest tag at the time of this post), but I do see it in https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/cae994ddbfe0.zip

Comment: 3.2.8 is a stable release. Unstable will be likely 3.3.x, according to their home page.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you might want to use the [KroneckerProduct module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__KroneckerProduct__Module.html) which is:

```
#include <Eigen/KroneckerProduct>

Eigen::MatrixXd X = Eigen::kroneckerProduct(A, B); 
// A and B are Eigen matrices.
```

Comment: No. I want to use Tensors, not Matrices or Arrays or Vectors.