# Storing 3D data with Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I store a 3D data using Eigen C++ library? Vector is for 1D data, Matrix is for 2D data but what is for a 3D data? Or is it possible to create a vector of matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional arrays in eigen library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917762/multidimensional-arrays-in-eigen-library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Tensor module. It is not yet stable though.

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> epsilon(4,5,6);  // 3 dimensions (4x5x6)
epsilon.setZero();
epsilon(0,1,2) = 1;
epsilon(0,2,1) = -1;
```

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support

Comment: Do you think if this: std::vector<MatrixXd> would be better? And what kind of issues can I get using this tensor?

Comment: I depends on your use case. If you can't afford refactoring the code, take the std::vector<MatrixXd> approach. I personally prefer going for the best suited approach (i.e. Tensor<>) in the first place.