# Eigen matrix in cpp

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen, eigen3

How to create a dynamic 3d matrix using the Eigen library. and how can slice the particular channel, in that channel slice some height and width?

example:

I want to create a matrix of size `3 * 320 * 240` (here channel width and height known at runtime), and then select a slice of `3 * 3` in each channel.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704691/storing-3d-data-with-eigen-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704691/storing-3d-data-with-eigen-library)

Comment: How it is possible without using tensor

Comment: You could potentially just create a vector of matricies.

Comment: In eigen tensor how indexing is done.  In numpy we use arr[:, 0:3, 0:3] what is equivalent of this in eigen?

Comment: Did you check http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    int a = 320;
    int b = 240;

    // Create as many as you want, probably better in a loop.
    MatrixXd m(a, b);
    MatrixXd n(a, b);
    MatrixXd o(a, b);

    std::vector<MatrixXd> v;
    v.push_back(m);
    v.push_back(n);
    v.push_back(o);

    std::cout << v.at(0)(0, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It should rather be `v.at(channel_no).block<3, 3>(i,j)`, because OP asked about 3x3 slice.